# Visual studio 2015+TFS 2015 is not working with Windows server 2003

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015, windows-server-2003, tfs-2015

I have VS2015+TFS client 2015 installed on my machine.
I am trying to connect to TFS server which is installed on windows server 2003 and getting below error:

```
TF31002:Unable to connect to  this Team Foundation Server......
........................
......................

Technical information( for administrator)
The remote server returned an error: (404) not found
```

if I try to connect the same TFS server using VS2010+TFS 2010 ,it is working fine. Can you guys please suggest what could be the issue? Compatibility?
Any work-around?

Answer (score 2):

Please check the [Requirements and compatibility](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/requirements) page. The supported server operating systems for TFS 2015 are as below:

- Windows Server 2012 R2 (Essentials, Standard, Datacenter)
- Windows Server 2012 (Essentials, Standard, Datacenter)
- Windows Server 2008 R2 (minimum SP1) (Standard, Enterprise,
  Datacenter)

Comment: Thanks for the information! But is there any workaround for this so that someone can use it with windows server 2003?

Comment: No, we can't change the system requirement.